# MongoDB - Problems with database design and statistical data calculation

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am currently facing a problem with MongoDB and that's probably due to my schema design, but I am unsure how to go about it.

So basically I have this collection (mongoose Schema):

```
const PlayerStatsCollection = {
  sportType: MongoId,
  player: MongoId,
  match: MongoId,
  team: MongoId,
  date: Date,
  league: MongoId,
  results: {
    _id: MongoId,
    value: String,
    name: String
  }
};
```

Results Arrya here works as Key Value Dictionary, where the key is the  _id. In other words, all the documents will share those subDocuments _ids (these are generate by clients)

This collection can and will have multiple results with the same (player,team,match,league,sportType) combos. So when querying I will need to group the data by these attributes (Or a subset of those) and I will need to sum the value of each of the results

I can potentially have millions of records in this collection

**Example :** 
So if I had two records with player = 0, and I wanted to query the stats for that player, I would get just one result with the results array being "merged" and the value summed by value key (result._id).

```
 {
        $match: {
          team: args.home
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            player: "$player",
            team: "$team",
            rankId: "$results._id"
          },
          value: { $sum: "$value" }
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            player: "$_id.player",
            team: "$_id.team"
          },
          stats: { $addToSet: { attribute: "$id.rankId", value: "$value" } }
        }
      }
```

This works somewhat, but my issue is how can I get the Top 5-10 Max pairs (player,..., result._id) with the highest value?  The current solution would require me to query the database multiple times one for each result._id; 
**A bit more info on what I am trying to accomplish:**

The PlayerStatsCollection has data according to a set of events that can occur stored in the results array. I want to use those events to calculate rankings based on a set of criteria. for example, I want to be able to query who was the player with the highest (event type) on a given date range. I also want to be able to query who was the highest player with the highest (event type) and on team x on certain date range.

I also thought in creating a secondary collection (mapReduce for example) to store the rankings on a separate collection, but I am not seeing how this would work to support the kind of queries I need.

I don't want a full solution, but just a few pointers on how to design/tackle this, maybe I am missing something or have some flaws in my thought process I am not noticing.

Any suggestion is welcome.